# How to load au_date format values into a redshift table (yy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yy)

Tags: python, sql, date, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load my csv file into my redshift table.

Here is what my csv file looks like:

```
id  | date1      | au_date      |us_date

1   , 2011-01-10 , 26/01/2011 ,  2011-01-10
```

Here is my code:

```
   create table if not exists schema1.table1(
            id int primary key encode zstd not null,
            date1   date encode AZ64 ,
            au_date date encode AZ64,
            us_date date encode AZ64
    );


copy schema1.table1
    from 's3:/path_to_file/file.csv'
    credentials 'my_role'
    region 'us-west-1'
    ESCAPE delimiter ','
    IGNOREHEADER 1
    ACCEPTANYDATE
    dateformat 'auto';
```

When I select * from the table it looks like:

```
 id  | date1      | au_date      |us_date

    1   , 2011-01-10 , null ,  2011-01-10
```

As you can see the au_date column is null because it doesn't pick of the date format of dd-mm-yy.

Any ways to fix this issue? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: I would suggest that you load the table as strings and then convert to a date within the database.

Comment: Land it in a staging table with everything as strings, then you can convert and load to your target table.

Comment: As you can define only one date format in COPY clause, you really have only two options: have csv file with unified date format or load data as strings and convert later on as already suggested.